# Would like to avoid duplicate entries in a ArrayList

Tags: java

I am looking for an object like ArrayList that would let me avoid duplicate entries.
For example it might have a method that calls 'contains()' to valid each entry before it is added to the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
if(!al.contains("red")){
  al.add("red");
}
```

Does something like this exist?

Comment: This question is more suited to StackOverflow.  What you are looking for is a Set (java.util.Set), most likely java.util.HashSet.

Answer (score 8):

ArrayLists, and Lists in general aren't designed to avoid duplicates, they're designed as a type of collection that maintains the order of a number of elements. If you want a collection more suited for the job then you want a set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

You can then add all you want to the set and it will never contain duplicate strings. Note that if you're using this with a class you wrote yourself then you'll need to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` for this to work properly.

As in the comment below, if you do still need to maintain order *and* remove duplicates, then `LinkedHashSet` is your friend.

Comment: And if maintaining order is needed, use `LinkedHashSet`.